# Accessing controls using C# code behind in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, reference, code-behind, xname

I can't access a label defined in the xaml file from the code behind C# code.

I tried the `x:name="l"` property but it tells me that "'l' is not defined":

[image]

Could anyone help me how to access controls from C# code behind by providing an example?

Comment: what you're doing is correct, but the XF Intellisense is pretty flaky.  Try restarting VS, and do a clean and build to see i that fixes it

Comment: @Jason Thanks unloading and reloading the project really did the trick put this solution for me to mark it as answer thanks again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

what you're doing is correct, but the XF Intellisense is pretty flaky. Try restarting VS, and do a clean and build to see i that fixes it

Comment: Just restarting VS (VS2017 in my case) sorted this. Who'd have thought eh ?

Comment: The problem persists (and your solution to it still works, thank you very much!) in 2022.